# JavaScript event listener not working on phone

Tags: javascript

EventListener is not working on mobile. This script is working properly on a PC, but it's not working on mobile phone. I have tried `onclick` too then or other function, but I don't know why none of them are working on a mobile phone.

I have tried many different ways to solve my problem, but none of them work. I don't want to use Jquery for this, I want to use pure JavaScript.

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="ABA" onclick="ra()" value="Applied Behaviour Analysis">Applied Behaviour Analysis
<div id="ss" style="display: none;">
  <input type="range" id="myText" value="1" min='1' max="4"><br>

  <!-- <input type="number" id="my" value="1" onmouseout="ss()" min="1" class="form-range"> -->
  
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function ra() {
    var a = document.getElementById('ss');

    if (a.style.display == "none") {
      a.style.display = "block";
    } else if (a.style.display == "block") {
      a.style.display = "none";
    }

  }

  document.getElementById("myText").addEventListener("click", myFunction)

  /* myFunction toggles between adding and removing the show class, which is used to hide and show the dropdown content */
  function myFunction() {
    alert("why not working?")
  }
</script>
```

Anyone help me out with this?

Thank you.

Comment: If I'm not terribly mistaken, `element.style.whatever` always returns a blank string (only the `set` function does something). If you want to check the CSS you'd have to do something else or use jQuery.

Comment: what should I do? I'm not very much familier with this.

Comment: Instead of trying to get the style, you can create a variable (or `data-` attribute) to tell you whether the text is displayed or not.

Comment: Read about [Touch Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) - should help solve your issue.

Comment: @RandyCasburn but what should do for laptop? then because ```touchend``` not work with mouse click

Comment: You'll need both types of events handled. You'll need to makes sure you read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events#handling_clicks) too.

Comment: Notice, it's possible to create a loop to attach multiple events type to the same function. Also for clarity and good understanding, jquery is not used or required here.